# How to choose a crossword grid

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

I have two clues whose surfaces run together very neatly (no relation between the answers). How do I go about choosing a grid so they appear next to each other? E.g.

[Down clues]
4. Jay-Z is worried about end of music ...  (5)
5. ... and Beyonce', lacking basic literacy, is struggling to become preeminent in her field (7)

Obviously these don't make as much sense if they appear in a different order, or with other clues between them.

Comment: This question is not very clear. Perhaps you could provide a visual?

Comment: Choose a grid shape, place them adjacent to each other then fill? Unless you've got many constraints on your grid, it doesn't seem that hard to do...

Comment: Choosing the grid shape is the question. As far as I know there isn't a way to filter grids down to ones that have a 5 and a 7 adjacent in the clue list.

Comment: I will add a screenshot of Crossword Compilers grid selection page in a couple of days when I'm back at my desk if people think it will clarify the question.

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://www.crossword-compiler.com/) Crossword Compiler? The templates are stored in a file called `Standard.glb` in a straightforward binary format, so perhaps one could write a little program to create a grid statistics dump for each grid? (It would be more useful if that were part of the regular program interface, of course.)

Comment: I know this isn't really an answer to the question, but the first 15x15 template in Crossword Compiler has a five-letter entry followed by a seven-letter one at 23 and 24 across.

Answer (score 1):

You could always go the more difficult route and try to make a grid from scratch. [Crossword Hobbyist](https://crosswordhobbyist.com/) (I'm not affiliated with them) is a great tool for building a crossword to see how the words intersect. Outputting the final crossword is a paid feature of the website (30 day free trial, then \$5/month, or $4.25/month when billed annually), but it's at least a good visualization tool.